# Manipulate a random walk

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, random, animation

For a college project I am manipulating a random walk. I managed to make a walk but in the manipulation every time a step is added the manipulation shows an entirely different walk. I understand why it does that but that's not what I want. For now I am trying to make one walk for which the manipulation adds one step at a time but for which the walk stays the same (with specific points). Can anybody please help me?

This is my code:

```
h[n_] := Module[{randomt, xeny, allex, alley, eindx, eindy, coordinaten},
  randomt = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n]; 
  xeny = {Cos[randomt], Sin[randomt]};
  allex = xeny[[1]]; 
  alley = xeny[[2]];
  coordinaten = Transpose[{allex, alley}];
  PrependTo[coordinaten, {0, 0}]
  ]

locaties[lijst_] := Table[Total[lijst[[1 ;; n]]], {n, 1, Length[lijst]}]

allelocaties = locaties[h[10]]
```

`allelocaties` gives a list of points I want to use for my single walk.

The manipulation of my walk so far:

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[allelocaties[[t]], {1}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}], {t, 1, 10, 1}]
```

I thought I managed to make the walk but `Joined->True` doesn't work.

I'll be so grateful if one of you guys could help me.

Comment: It should be `ListPlot[allelocaties[[;; t]], Joined -> True,...`, this looks like it's working.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly! Do you also happen to know if there is a way that I could do it with more random walks in the same manipulation?

Comment: @SanneFeline 1. `Remove[allelocaties]`, 2. `allelocaties[1] = locaties[h[10]]; allelocaties[2] = locaties[h[10]];`, 3. `Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[allelocaties[i][[;; t]], {i, 1, 2}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}], {t, 1, 10, 1}]`

Comment: Thanks! But do you think that it is possible to make multiple randomwalks in one plot without making a lot of lists of coördinates?

Comment: Making a lists of lists (each list representing a random walk) and then passing that to `ListPlot` is what you want to do, if you want to display several walks at once. `Take[#, t] & /@ listOfList` will select only the `t` first elements in each walk.

Comment: It sounds helpful but I don't completely understand it. I made a list of lists `listoflists = Table[locaties[h[10]], {10}]` and then i tried to make the plot with: `Manipulate[ListPlot[Take[listoflists, t], {1}], 
 Joined -> True, {t, 1, 10, 1}]` but it gives multiple errors.

Comment: I made a manipulation that works: `Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Take[listoflists, t], Joined -> True], {t, 1, 10, 1}]` but it adds finished walks instead of it adding steps to multiple walks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @SanneFeline Well, that is the tricky part, that is why I gave you the solution :) `Take[#, t] & /@ listOfList` should go in the place of `Take[listoflists, t]` - `/@` is the same as `Map`, if you look it up in the documentation you will probably understand why this works.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much!!!!!